# SSH client error "Connection Time Out"

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, modem

I am trying to connect to an ec2 instance via a Java SSH client. The error I am getting is **Connection Time out**. Now the problem is either with

1. The Modem - [`DWM-156 HSUPA 3.75G USB ADAPTER`](http://www.dlink.co.in/products/?pid=459) *(I am using a wireless dongle to connect to internet)* or
2. ISP

The reason for my suspecting the error in one of these is because I can connect to the same ec2 instance via a wired internet connection with Siemens Modem.

**My Question**

Why I am not to connect to an ec2 instance over a wireless internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could be the poor connectivity. you might want to try mosh in this case.

http://mosh.mit.edu/

not sure if there is an equivalent java ssh client, however, that will be more tolerant of lost packets, high jitter, etc.

Comment: I have a PC with Windows 7, looks like mosh doen't run on Windows.

Comment: it runs under cygwin, though it may not be natively.